# Proving that the sequence space $l^1$ is complete

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, complete-spaces

I don't know how to figure this out :

[image]

Comment: Do you know Fatou's lemma for sums?

Comment: No I don't know the Lemma. Until now we didn't used it in University, so I am not allowed using it solving this problem.

Comment: It is better to avoid the use of pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers; please [edit] the question to correct that and also include your 
thoughts and the work you have done so far to solve the problem. If you need it, you will find is some basic information 
about writing math on MSE [here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Infinite Monkey, I agree with everything you said until the "show your work". This is not a calculus question and it is ridiculous to require someone to show their work at this level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $\{x_i^{n}\}$ is Cauchy so it is bounded, namely, $\exists M > 0$ such $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}{|x_i^{n}|} \leq M$. Thus, $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}{ |x_i^{n}|} \leq M$. Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ we get that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}{|x_i|} \leq M$. Since this holds for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, letting $k \to \infty$ we get that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}{|x_i|} \leq M$. Thus, $x=\{x_i\} \in \ell^1(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: @Chopin, If you are just getting use to working with $\ell^p$ spaces $1 \leq p < \infty$ may I recommend as few exercises that will help your understanding. First generalizing this result to show that $\ell^p$ for $1 \leq p < \infty$ is are complete. Secondly, to show that these spaces are separable. Lastly, can you show that $\ell^2$ is an inner product, namely the $|| \cdot ||_2$ arises from an inner product and thus is actually a Hilbert Space.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help. I don't know what stage you are at, but lastly, you should at some point show that $\ell^2$ is the canonical separable Hilbert space.